# What similar command to "xload" in linux will be for os x?

Tags: linux, macos, command, line

In linux (I am using Ubuntu 15.04) there is a small program supplied with the X Window system called xload which displays a graph representing system load. I can excute this program by typing in command line the following: xload. I tried xload in command line on mac. But it said "command not found" My question is "What command, which is similar to xload in linux, should I use in command line for Mac OS X (El Capitan)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want a windowed app or not. Assuming yes, then try

```
open -a "Activity Monitor"
```

Comment: How can it be in different way not a windowed app?

Comment: The command `top` render only in text mode